# Vue.js Image Aspect Ratio

Tags: node.js, css, vue.js, material-design

I'm creating my new social network. I encountered new problem, or rather I can't think of a way to implement the solution that I have. When user uploads an image, I want to have boxes that keep aspect ratio of the image, but also keep post same width. I want to use that CSS trick with padding, but I don't know how to dynamicaly calculate aspect ratio and attach it to style of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I 100% follow but if you want a image to have a image with a set width while the height is based on its aspect ratio. Simply set the image width with CSS and left the height to auto.

If you wanna wrap it in a box (div) you can set the width to the box and set the image to 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`v-aspect-ratio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-aspect-ratio) directive.